# PHP script not found by Java but works in browser

Tags: java, php, mysqli, ubuntu-12.10

I have several PHP sripts saved in my /var/www/ directory. I can run them from my browser but Java can't see them.

Here is output from browser:

[image]

And from Java:

```
DB: Error executing script: get_profile_ids
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found [Date: Tue, 16 Apr 2013 11:52:40 GMT, Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu), Vary: Accept-Encoding, Content-Length: 288, Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100, Connection: Keep-Alive, Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1]
DB: Result:
```

My Java code:

```
public class ServerTest {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        callPHPScript("get_print_profile_ids", new ArrayList<NameValuePair>());

    }

    public static String callPHPScript(String scriptName, List<NameValuePair> parameters) {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost/" + scriptName);
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200)
            {
                System.out.println("DB: Error executing script: " + scriptName);
                System.out.println(response.toString());
            }
            else {
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()));
                line = "";
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("DB: Result: " + stringBuilder.toString());
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

And my PHP Script:

```
<?php
include('connect_db.php');
include('tools.php');

$query = 'SELECT id FROM fingerprint_profiles';

$result = mysql_query($query);
echo($result);

?>
```

Does anybody know why this might happen??

Comment: Seems like you're missing `.php` where you're calling the script.

Comment: You may have a typo, the PHP file in the browser says `get_print_profile_ids`, you're calling `get_profile_ids`...

Comment: I had all this code working on a different machine, I don't think .php is required...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the .php, change:
`HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost/" + scriptName);`
to
`HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost/" + scriptName + ".php");`

Comment: It looks like this was the problem ! I don't understand though, I had all this code working on a different machine and I never put .php in..

Comment: It could be that your other machine was configured differently to append .php automatically on the server.

Answer (score 1):

here's the hint:

```
System.out.println("DB: Error executing script: " + scriptName);
```

is logging

```
DB: Error executing script: get_profile_ids
```

change your test call to

```
callPHPScript("get_profile_ids.php", new ArrayList<NameValuePair>());
```

and you'll likely get a successful result.

Answer (score 1):

Your Java code calls `get_profile_ids` while your browser screenshot shows `get_profile_ids.php`. Change your Java code to call `get_profile_ids.php` as well.